# How can we use a linked lists for the parent-child relationships in a suffix tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, suffix-tree

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), an important choice when making a suffix tree implementation is the parent-child relationships between nodes. The most common one is using linked lists called sibling lists.

How does this work in Java?

Answer (score 2):

In a sibling list, each node has exactly two references: `first-child` and `next-sibling`. This lets you iterate over all the children of a node by starting with `first-child`, and then following `next-sibling` until you get to the child whose `next-sibling` is `null`. I don't see why Java would be any different from any other programming language.

It's interesting to note that this representation is virtually identical to the standard representation of a binary tree, where `left` is spelled `first-child` and `right` is spelled `next-sibling`. This demonstrates the `1-1` relationship between binary trees and general trees with the same number of nodes. (It might seem contradictory at first, but note that a binary tree may have only a `left` child, or only a `right` child, and those are considered different. By contrast, in a general tree, there is only one way for a node to have one child.

Answer (score -1):

Parent has a list of child nodes (either as array, double linked list or so)
Each child has a link to its parent. Traversing is extremely simple as you don't need a stack.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. What do you expect? It works the same way as it works for all programming languages.